# Extract substring in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring

I am trying to write a method in C, which will extract a substring between a starting and ending string. Based on a boolean flag it might include/exclude the starting substring.
i.e,

```
 char source[100] = "Some random text with $$KEY:value$$";
 char dest[12];
 extractSubstring (source, dest, "KEY:", "$", false);
```

this should populate dest = "value".

My program is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

int main()
{
    char source[100] = "Some random text with $$KEY:value$$";
    char dest[12];
    extractSubstring (source, dest, "KEY:", "$", false);
    return 0;
}

void extractSubstring (char *source, char *dest, char *startingText,
          char *endingText, bool includeStart)
{
    int sourceLen = strlen(source);
    int startLen = strlen(startingText);
    int endingIndex = sourceLen;
    source = strstr (source, startingText);
    if(includeStart){
        strcpy (dest, source);
    }
    else{
       source+=startLen;
       strcpy (dest, source);
    }
    if(strlen(endingText)>0){
        int endingIndex = strstr (dest, endingText) - dest;

    }
    dest[endingIndex] = '\0';
    printf(dest);
}
```

This is populating dest as "value$$" instead of "value". How to discard the last characters.

Comment: `int endingIndex = strstr (dest, endingText) - dest;` shadows a variable.and the `dest[endingIndex] = '\0';` after it can write out of bounds.

Comment: What a silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from lifetime of variables (endingIndex here). Removing the `int` should do the trick, but I recommend not writing unnecessary chars to dest (risking an overflow). 
(Also, you should use `size_t` type for array lengths.)
You should optimize the way the string is written this way:

```
void extractSubstring (char *source, char *dest, char *startingText,
          char *endingText, bool includeStart)
{
    size_t sourceLen = strlen(source);
    size_t startLen = strlen(startingText);
    size_t endingIndex = sourceLen;
    source = strstr (source, startingText);
    if(!includeStart){
       source+=startLen;
    }

    if(strlen(endingText)>0){
        endingIndex = strstr (source, endingText) - source;
        strncpy(dest, source, endingIndex);
    } else {
        strcpy (dest, source);
    }

    dest[endingIndex] = '\0';
    printf(dest);
}
```

Hope it helps.

[EDIT : [wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser) comment explains it well]

Comment: `source = strstr (source, startingText);
    if(!includeStart){
       source+=startLen;
    } ... strstr (source, endingText) - source;` looks iffy as `source` may be `NULL` when `source` is used again.

Comment: `source` might be `NULL` if it was `NULL` in the first place, or if `startingText` is equal to `source`. Should be the precondition of the function I guess. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `source = strstr (source, startingText);` is missing a path to take if the pattern is not found. Code would benefit  with something like `char *f = strstr (source, startingText); if (f) do_this(f) else do_that;`